# Totally confused about stateful and stateless LSTM networks and the input_shape respectively

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

Let's say I've got 2500 time series of class A, each 17 time steps long:

```
Time series a_1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Time series a_2: [10,11,12,13,12,11,10,11,12,13,12,11,10,11,12,13,14]
...
Times series a_2500: [3,5,7,5,3,5,7,5,3,5,7,5,3...]
```

And I've got 2500 time series of class B, again 17 time steps long:

```
Time series b_1: [3, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7, 4, 1]
Time series b_2: [12,41,54,64,12,53,12,12,43,21,32,1, 32,31,53,12,1]
...
Time series b_2500: [some more random numbers]
```

There is only one numerical feature per time series, the number from above. I want to train a LSTM using Keras to classify the time series into one of the two classes. They should be be easily distinguishable using features which require the LSTM to understand the time correlation between the data, the class A has a seasonal has a seasonal pattern, while B hasn't.

My problem is now the difference between a statless and a statefull LSTM and how to construct the input_dimension for the LSTM network. As far as I understand it the input for the LSTM is defined as `(batch_size, time steps, features)`. I'll try to present the two variants of modeling this problem, one which I assume would be the "stateless" solution, and the other the "statefull" one. If so, which one is preferable? And if not, what would be the two solutions?

**Variant 1 - stateless solution**

My X is now `(batch_size,17,1)`. That means one batch contains multiple time series.

X would be in that example:

```
[
                [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [3], [2], ..., [4]] # <- this here is time series a_1
                [[3], [6], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], ..., [1]] # <- this here is time series b_1
                [[10], [11], [12], [13],          ..., .[14]] # <- this here is time series a_2
                ... # <- continue for all time series for one batch
]
```

I can now use f.e. a batch_size of 32 and train my LSTM using different time series at a time, and while predicting I can just show it a batch of one time series and will get an output?

**Variant 2 - stateful solution**

Or do I show the time series each time step at a time, so my input is `(1,1,1)` and I just show it then for each time series 17 times per each time step the single feature? I would then call after I'm finished with one time series the model.reset_states() method to forget everything for the new time series?

So I use an X of `[[[0]]]` (first time step from a_1), fit the model, show it `[[[1]]]` (second time step from `a_1`), fit the model, etc. If I reach the last time step of `a_1` I call model.reset_state() and can proceed with all time steps from `b_1`?

And for the stateful solution I need to use a batch size of 1, because if I would train it with multiple time series at once I would have to always let it classify multiple time series at once during predicting too, so I can't use a different batch size during training and testing?

Comment: consider sharing parts of code , I am not able to follow the shapes at all, kindly consider adding two rows of features (input data)

Comment: Updated, I hope I could make it clearer!

Comment: To answer to the question: if you can use different batch size in training and prediction yes absolutely you can, just while you define a place holder instread of giving it a shape[batch,17,1], give it shape [None,17,1].

Comment: Variant 2 isn't the correct way to do things.